# Drawing Heat Map on iOS

Tags: ios, heatmap

I'm developing iOS app and I want to add/draw an HeatMap without using Google maps or any kind of map. I just want to draw it on my View. I have been looking for an open source library for iOS but I didn't find any.

Do anyone know a way how do I draw an HeatMap on View in iOS?

Here is an example for what I'm looking for but it's for Android platform:

https://github.com/HeartlandSoftware/AndroidHeatMap

Thanks, Tal.

Answer (score 0):

in github enter in search field:

language:swift heatmap

you will get:

https://github.com/jamesdouble/JDSwiftHeatMap

Comment: Thanks for you answer, It based on MKMapView and it's not what I'm looking for. I don't use MKMapView in my app.

Comment: @TalSahar I know this is late, but you should be able to make use of a MKMapView and this library without even showing the map. You would eventually need to create an image from the map. Anyway, hope you got a solution at the time.

Comment: @pnizzle, thanks for your comment. I have already implemented it using MetalKit.

Comment: @TalSahar would you be able to please share the implementation as an answer. Lots would benefit from it including myself :)

Comment: @TalSahar Hey, would you be able to share how you did it in Metal. I'm quite curious to see your solution as I'm about to try it myself too.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a heatmap that doesn't require a MKMapView and one that you can just place over an image, you could try this cocoapod

pod 'LFHeatMap'

https://github.com/gpolak/LFHeatMap.

Before you consider it for your project just know that you can't adjust the colour gradient of the "heat" without hacking the library a little. But it's pretty easy to use:

```
let points: [CGPoint] = [CGPoint(x: 25, y: 25),
                             CGPoint(x: 125, y: 125),
                             CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)]
    let image = LFHeatMap.heatMap(with: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300),
                                  boost: 0.5,
                                  points: points,
                                  weights: nil)
    let overlayHeatMap = UIImageView(image: image)
    self.view.addSubview(overlayHeatMap)
    overlayHeatMap.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 50, width: 300, height: 300)
```

If you're interested in changing the colour you can fiddle with code around line 411 in LFHeatMap.m below the comment that says '// Red and alpha component'

Comment: Hey Jan, I'm using your exact code, and the image it's blank, without errors.

Comment: @SebasBejenaru Ah geez, sorry. My example points were outside of the image. If you change the points to be above (x:50, y:100) or change the heatMap's x and y to be 0, it should work. I'll update my example code above.

Comment: Thanks Jan! It's so fast generating it! amazing, I'm going to modify to add gradient colors :)